# Can not start service on Android 6

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

My problem appears on android Marshmallow, if apk file is debug then everything works OK, but on release mode can not startService, not crashes just goes to sleep. Code is simple 
`Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, WorkService.class);
  startService(intent);` , also tried

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            if (null == WorkService.workThread) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, WorkService.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

result is the same, WorkService :

```
public class WorkService extends Service {

public static WorkThread workThread = null;
private static Handler mHandler = null;
private static List<Handler> targetsHandler = new ArrayList<>(5);

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mHandler = new MHandler(this);
    workThread = new WorkThread(mHandler);
    workThread.start();
    Log.v("DrawerService", "onCreate");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.v("DrawerService", "onStartCommand");
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.what = Global.MSG_ALLTHREAD_READY;
    notifyHandlers(msg);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    workThread.disconnectBt();
    workThread.disconnectNet();
    workThread.disconnectUsb();
    workThread.quit();
    workThread = null;
    Log.v("DrawerService", "onDestroy");
}

static class MHandler extends Handler {

    WeakReference<WorkService> mService;

    MHandler(WorkService service) {
        mService = new WeakReference<>(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        notifyHandlers(msg);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param handler
 */
public static void addHandler(Handler handler) {
    if (!targetsHandler.contains(handler)) {
        targetsHandler.add(handler);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param handler
 */
public static void delHandler(Handler handler) {
    if (targetsHandler.contains(handler)) {
        targetsHandler.remove(handler);
    }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param msg
 */
public static void notifyHandlers(Message msg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < targetsHandler.size(); i++) {
        Message message = Message.obtain(msg);
        targetsHandler.get(i).sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

}

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Be more specific about what is happening. Tell us exactly what is different between those two runs of your app.

Comment: On api level < 23 WorkService starts and works, on 23 api level, on line startService phone hangs and after few seconds offers close application or wait more

Comment: Why do you have the `startService()` call in another Thread?

Comment: Error is the same even if I call from UI